# how to use interface as object class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, orchardcms, autofac

i want to use interface as object class. like what you see in some CMS s like Orchard. For Example you can use IContentManager interface like an object that does many operations about contents. or even use interface as ViewModel (First one has priority).
I used Autofac to do some thing like

```
public class BLL_DependencySetup : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<RoleService>().As<IRoleService>();
        builder.RegisterType<RoleMV>().As<IRole>().InstancePerDependency();
        base.Load(builder);
    }
}
```

but actually its not like what exactly I want.

```
public class ISRelatedContentsDriver : ContentPartDriver<ISRelatedContentsPart>
{
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;

    public ISRelatedContentsDriver(IContentManager contentManager)
    {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
    }
```

I want to do some thing like you see above. Does it have any relation with IoC ?
**Edit:** i just want to know how its working. and using that in my own architecture. not in orchard.

Comment: Explain what behavior you want. "use interface as object class" is not clear.

Comment: @CodeCaster second code block is like what i want ...its part of an orchard module which use IContentManager to do some thing on blog posts(like select top 10 or ...). i want to do same thing in my architecture. means dont use my classes directly. just use their parent interfaces or ...

Answer (score 1):

Your class or interface needs to inherit from `IDependency`.
Then you can inject it like any other service in Orchard.

For Example:

```
public interface MyInterface : IDependency
{
   void DoSomething();
}

public MyClass : MyInteface
{
   public void DoSomething()
   {
      // work
   }
}

public class ISRelatedContentsDriver : ContentPartDriver<ISRelatedContentsPart>
{
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
    private readonly IMyInterface _myInterface;

    public ISRelatedContentsDriver(IContentManager contentManager, IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
        _myInterface = myInterface;
    }
}
```

Comment: i just want to know how its working. and using that in my own architecture. not in orchard. IDependecy in orchards custom interface

Comment: My apologies, I've misunderstood your question. I think your question is just related to autofac then. However, here's [how orchards IDependency gets actually registered](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard/Environment/ShellBuilders/ShellContainerFactory.cs) if you want to copy that mechanism. I'd check out the source and F12 my way through it, but a pure Autofac tutorial should be more fitting for your case.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are seeking for is Dependency Injection and yes it's in relation with IoC. You need an IoC container ([Autofac](https://autofac.org/), [Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor), [Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/), etc.) to register your interfaces and there implementation. And then you'll be able to use your services like you wanted above.

I'd suggest you to go through one of the IoT container's tutorial or think about it again that you whether want to build a new architecture or not.